# How to hide the dots in FMX TabControl?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol

I do not want to show the dots in a TabControl interface, when I change the properties of TabControl, TabPosition: Dots ... I just want to handle it with gestures.

Comment: What dots? Are you talking about the Firemonkey TabControl on iOS and Android?

Comment: Yes!!!, firemonkey, Andriod...Thanks.

Comment: @Dsm It's not just iOS and Android - it applies to all platforms supported by FMX.

Comment: @JerryDodge thanks, yes I know, but it is the platform default for iOS, and I think for Android, and I was trying to get clarification.

Answer (score 7):

Set the TabPosition property to None.

It can seem misleading because the dots still show up in design mode to simplify moving from page to page when designing, but they will not show when running.